# Control price change after every swap in DEX

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts, cryptocurrency, binance-smart-chain

I am new to the development of DEX. Can we able to control the price of our own token of certain increase/decrease in price after every swap through swapping router contract.
https://testnet.bscscan.com/address/0xD99D1c33F9fC3444f8101754aBC46c52416550D1#code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to control the price of the swap on a bonding curve exchange is to trade against it.

If someone sells, you buy.

If someone buys, you sell.

Comment: We are fixing the price of the tokens by adding initial liquidity in our DEX. Is my understanding is correct?

Comment: How can we fetch the current market price to our DEX...

Comment: "We are fixing the price of the tokens by adding initial liquidity in our DEX. Is my understanding is correct?" Your understanding is incorrect. This does not move the price.

Comment: "How can we fetch the current market price to our DEX" This is unrelated question. I suggest you read StackOverflow tutorial how to ask good questions and then open a separate question for this.

Comment: Ok. Then on which basis we have to add initial liquidity.